# How to insert a `React` component after a child element?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a `React` component and insert it after a child element.  Here is the markup.

```js
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
</li>
```

I want to insert my `React` component after the `<a>` tag, but not a child of the `<a>` tag.  Here is what I want it to look like.

```js
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Other <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul ... this is my React component>

  </ul>
</li>
```

Here is the code that adds the component:

```js
React.renderComponent(new NavbarDropdown(), this.$el.find('WHAT GOES HERE').get(0));
```

I do not want to add a div with an `id` to place it into, so how would I add the `React` component in that location?

Comment: Btw, use the dev build of React. You'll see a warning that `class` should be `className.

Answer (score 1):

React needs to render the component onto *something*. So you could place a placeholder `div` there.

Comment: Is there a way to have it `replace` instead of `append`?

Comment: No, at least not yet. It's easier this way when you do `unmountComponentAtNode`.